# Projections in LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a challenge to  use Select new

Normally we do

```
var record = from s in db.Settings
             select new
             {
                 myID = s.ID,
                 customName = s.PkGuid
             };
```

But we can't do Select new if I have like:

```
CacheHelper.Settings().Select(a => ???????)
```

Any one?!

Thanks :)

Comment: more information, why can't you do that? what is your problem? error message? what would you like to type instead of `???????`? And why do you have "(advanced)" in your question? It doesn't provide any information, and the question doesn't seem to be that "advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made me uncertain for 30ms!

```
var record = CacheHelper.Settings().Select(a => new {
             myID = a.ID,
             customName = a.PkGuid
         });
```

Comment: that's exactly what I meant with my comment... is this what he really wants? and why would that be advanced? and why not read about how things work before asking a question? I sort of hope that this is not the answer he wants :).

Comment: You'r right - thats why I was uncertain! His question looks like, he want to transform a "sql like" linq syntax into a "function like" syntax. I'm also curious why he is asking.

Comment: I googled a lot for this. But couldn't find it. Thanks @Arthur